# how to insert content into my taxonomy

Tags: php, custom-taxonomy

how to insert content into my taxonomy
                   this code is correct or not?

```
   // Create post object
  $my_post = array(
 'post_title' => 'My post',
 'post_content' => 'This is my post.',
 'post_status' => 'publish',
 'post_author' => 1,
  'tax_input' => array( 'taxonomy_name' => array( 'Newpostlist' ) ) , 
 'post_category' => array(8,39),

   );

      // Insert the post into the database
       wp_insert_post( $my_post );
```

Comment: Taxonomies don’t have content, they are _meta data_.

Comment: He means "insert terms associated with a taxonomy"

Answer (score 1):

You're using `tax_input` incorrectly. You're not literally supposed to say `taxonomy_name`, you're supposed to enter the name of your custom taxonomy. See https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post. So, assuming your taxonomy is called 'ninja_turtles' and you are tagging your post with 'donatello' and 'michelangelo':

```
// Create post object
$my_post = array(
    'post_title' => 'My post',
    'post_content' => 'This is my post.',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post_author' => 1,
    'tax_input' => array( 'ninja_turtles' => array( 'donatello', 'michelangelo' ) ) , 
    'post_category' => array(8,39),
);

// Insert the post into the database
wp_insert_post( $my_post );
```

For no particular reason (other than that it makes me feel like I have more granular control), I personally prefer not to use `tax_input` but to use the standalone function `wp_set_post_terms()` https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_post_terms after the post is created:

```
// Create post object
$my_post = array(
    'post_title' => 'My post',
    'post_content' => 'This is my post.',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post_author' => 1,
    'post_category' => array(8,39),
);

// Insert the post into the database
$post_id = wp_insert_post( $my_post );

// If all was successful, add the terms
if ( $post_id ) {
    wp_set_post_terms( $post_id, array( 'donatello', 'michelangelo' ), 'ninja_turtles' );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code appears to be correct, but the only way to find out is to try it. You can find more information about adding posts at the [`wp_insert_post()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post) page on the WordPress codex.